# adding all swf files from dir to player in vb

Tags: vb.net

how can i add all swf files from dir to player in vb by just selecting directory....and play it in shockwave flash player in vb.......

i have tested a swf file and it is working fine now how can i achieve the above target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

best way i would suggest is,

put all these in a xml or flat file.

in your VB, read the file and play it like a playlist.